# Uncountable noun 1 OR Uncountable 2 ARE/IS

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

I have just read the following:

> These design rules play an important role, and reworking or enhancement of their function represent a possible outcome of ...

Why not "represents"? I thought it is like either A or B is (one of these things).

Thanks a lot

Comment: More context is needed. It might be A and B where B is "reworking or .. function"

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: I think represents is correct.

Comment: I'd say that "reworking or enhancement" represents a single idea, so the verb should be the singular "represents